# Mobile App, How to make a html parser code dynamic because the html content may change

Tags: android, html, ios, parsing, dynamic

I use HttpClient to get a html page, I use regexp to extract content from it, and organize the data, display it in a listview/tableview.

The page is not owned by me, so the content may change, everytime the content change, and even sometimes the url changes, I need to modify the parser or url, and update the whole app.

I want to know how to make this parser more dynamic, and easy to update-to-date, make my app partially updated for just this module.

The mobile app works on Android/iOS devices.

Comment: Use tags only that contain the content you need to fetch. And for variable url try using http://www.google.com/search?q=your-query-&btnI=3564 Google's I'm feeling lucky :) :) . Or have predefined server from which you feed the urls to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when your app runs you could have it request the URL and the RegExp pattern string to use from a page somewhere that you *do* control.  That way if the third party page content or URL changes you can update you page with the values and you wouldn't have to update your app every time.